# How to export instanced collections to unity and retain the heirarchal format of an object?

Tags: export, unity, .fbx, collections

I'm trying to export my scene with all its objects hierarchies into unity. However the instanced collections of the Sofa object does not have the same hierarchical format of the original collection when exported to unity.

How do I preserve this hierarchical format during exporting to unity?

Collection and instance in blender
[image]

Collection and instance in Unity
[image]

Comment: Collection is not supported by fbx, its a Blender exclusive thing to orgainze your objects. Add an empty to every collection and parent all the objects to it.

Comment: @FFeller what would that do?

Comment: preserve the hierarchy